# Show request/response info in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to show request/response headers for the given page in In Google Chrome? I know that great Network tab from built-in developer tools can be used, however, it needs to be activated beforehand.. but sometimes one needs to show the info of the unique event, which already happened.

Does Chrome/Chromium offer such info? (I looked at some relevant-looking resources from chrome://about, but could not find it.)

If not, what extension would you recommend?

(in Firefox, Live HTTP Headers add-on can be used, the headers are shown as an additional tab in the Page Info window)

Answer (score 1):

use [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). it shows you all outgoing/incoming http requests, and lets you inspect pretty much everything/anything you'd want to.

Comment: i believe there are people, who wouln't mind having non open-source SSL proxy on their machine.. i'm not one of them. thanks for hint anyway..

Answer (score 0):

You can install chrome-extension from here: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/search/Live%20HTTP?hl=ru